# Mongo aggregate $group issue

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this model data:

```
var orders = [{
  _id: 'order_1'
  users: [{
    name: 'Bob'
    _id: 'user_1',
    company: 'company_1'
  }, {
    name: 'John'
    _id: 'user_3',
    company: 'company_2'
  }]
}, {
  _id: 'order_2'
  users: [{
    name: 'Mary'
    _id: 'user_2',
    company: 'company_1'
  }]}];
```

Using the aggregate framework I would like to end up with:

```
 [{
  _id: 'user_1',
  order: 'order_1',
  company: 'company_1'
}, {
  _id: 'user_2',
  order: 'order_2',
  company: 'company_1'
}];
```

The code:

```
return Order.aggregateAsync([{
  $unwind: '$users'
}, {
  $match: {
    'users.company': 'company_1'
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    id: '$users._id',
    order: '$_id',
    company: '$users.company',
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$users"
  }
}]);
```

But something is not quite right. As soon as I add the $group param I lose all the data in the result and end up with just the user IDs in an array.

```
[ 
  { _id: 'user_1' },
  { _id: 'user_2' } 
]
```

How do I get all the data I projected back in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the rows are grouped, aggregate is not sure which row you need, unless you specify it. 
With `$group` you don't even need `$project`. This query may give you what you need:

```
return Order.aggregateAsync([{
  $unwind: '$users'
}, {
  $match: {
    'users.company': 'company_1'
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$users",
    id: { $first: '$users._id' },
    order: { $first: '$_id' },
    company: { $first: '$users.company' },
  }
}]);
```

I basically just moved your projection under grouping, where you can use anything like `$first`, `$last` or other expressions.